# Assign var from conditional right-hand side (sub)expression

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi

Looking for a way to keep variables on the left-hand side while assigning to them and I haven't found a concise way yet.

```
  [[ "${selections[@]}" =~ "${package}" ]] && is_pkg_selected=true || is_pkg_selected=false
  test_package_loaded $package && is_pkg_installed=true || is_pkg_installed=false

  # ideal would be like...
  is_pkg_selected=$([[ "${selections[@]}" =~ "${package}" ]])
  is_pkg_installed=$(test_package_loaded $package && true || false)
```

Any ideas? It's very hard to read vars with multiple lines together.

Scripts run on RaspberryPi running Raspbian so would prefer the most `sh` method possible.

Comment: What's wrong with `if sometest; then var=true; else var=false; fi`, possibly with newlines in place of semi-colons?  It's readable, it's maintainable, and it's unambiguous. Note that with `A && B || C`, the `C` command would execute if _either_ of `A` and `B` failed.

Comment: @Kusalananda readability is the primary concern. Yes, your code works but put 5 if-then-assign-else-assign-fi statements together with 15 character var names and it becomes very inefficient to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
is_pkg_selected=$([[ "${selections[@]}" =~ "${package}" ]] && echo true || echo false)
is_pkg_installed=$(test_package_loaded "$package" && echo true || echo false)
```

That is, you need to explicitly have `echo` or something like that in the command substitution to output the text to assign to the variable. (And it's text, remember, `true` and `false` there are just strings.)

Comment: Ah, that is very nice! Thank you!